# Json config file for mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have the following JSON configuration file for mongodb (named mongoConfig.json):

```
{
    "mongodb": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 27017,
      "database": "test"
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to use this file to connect to my database. So far I have tried to use it like this:

```
//mongoConn.ts

'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./../mongoConfig.json');

exports.connect = () => {
  return mongoose.connect(config.toString())
    .then(() => {     
      console.log("Successfully connected to database!");
      return mongoose.connection; });
};
```

but I've got the error: `` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid schema, expected `mongodb` or `mongodb+srv` ``

my folder structure is:

```
        |-.vs
        |-node_modules
        |-src
        |   └── connections
        |           └──mongoConn.ts
        |   └── mongoConfig.json
```

I'm a total beginner in using mongoDB and config files for it, so I'm guessing that I'm not using the JSON file correctly either...

Any help would be appreciated! :)

EDIT: Corrected the path! (from `'./mongoConfig.json'` to `'./../mongoConfig.json'`)

Comment: share your folder structure

Comment: try making ``mongoConfig`` **.js** file and do export / default export within file

Comment: @mehta-rohan updated the question

Comment: @fard Unfortunately, one of the requirements is that the mongoConfig file to be of type JSON :(

Comment: @user3063909 based on file tree you should do ``./../mongoConfig.json``

Comment: @fard you were right, thanks a lot! :) Right now I have to deal with another error... unfortunately... :(

Answer (score 0):

Mongooes.connect takes uri string in : `mongodb://username:password@host:port/database`. So try,

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');
```

OR

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database', options, function(error) {
  // Check error in initial connection. There is no 2nd param to the callback.
});
```